# Generate Signed APK isn't displayed in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, signed-apk

I am on Android Studio 3.6.3 and in order to publish my App to the Playstore, I need to generate a signed APK. As I learned in multiple consultations of the internet, there should be the option in the Menu->Build->*generate signed APK*. It is not there. Also, I can't change my Build Variants, *'nothing to show'* is displayed. I found in an older answer to set my Keystore up in the *Project structure* section, which is no longer possible, at least for me. So I went to the *build.gradle*, set up my Keystore, imported the Android-Certificate put all my credentials there. *Error in line 58, Could not get unknown property 'meister'*, was the result.
All options I found to generate this signed APK aren't working for me.
I just don't know how to help me now, other than asking you.

[missing option, generate signed APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag6g2.png)

Answer (score 4):

Build bundle(s) / Apk(s) is disabled in flutter

check the below links may help you

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac

[image: keyStore]

Comment: thank you for the answer. I followed the steps, new error: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'; error in line 26.

Answer (score 3):

For those who still got this issue when releasing Android Flutter app, I resolved this by:

1. Right click the Project root folder -> Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio.
2. Wait for the Gradle syncing
3. Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

seems like a problem with the IDE. try to rename .androidstudio file(it's usually is c:/users//.androidstudio 
then reopen android studio
let me know if it works

Comment: okay, so on a mac this is probably different. I searched in the hidden folders, couldn't find it. I deinstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it, nothing changed. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Also searched in the contents folder, which is behind the application. not quite sure what to do.

Comment: I tried it on Parallels, which confronted me with the same kind of problems. As I followed the steps you described the following occurred. Each time I renamed it, another new folder, called Android Studio 3.6, was appearing as soon as I opened the program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the recommended method, but I also did not have the generate APK/ app bundle option in Android Studio. What worked for me was to right-click on the Android folder of my project in Android Studio. I selected "Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio" in a new window. I then could see "Build > Generate APK" in Android Studio.